# DataOutputStream equivalent for Dart

Tags: dart

I am looking for a Java DataOutputStream equivalent for Dart where I can write arbitrary types (int, string, float, byte array etc). There is RandomAccessFile but it does not provide byte array or float-double values. ByteArray seems to have some necessary functions but I am not sure how to  write it to a file or an OutputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some simple code showing how to write a ByteArray into an OutputStream:

```
#import('dart:io');
#import('dart:scalarlist');

main() {
        File file = new File("c:\\temp\\foo.txt");
        OutputStream os = file.openOutputStream();
        os.onNoPendingWrites = () {
                print('Finished writing. Closing.');
                os.flush();
                os.close();
        };
        Uint8List byteList = new Uint8List(64);
        ByteArray byteArray = byteList.asByteArray();
        int offset = 0;
        offset = byteArray.setUint8(offset, 72);
        offset = byteArray.setUint8(offset, 101);
        offset = byteArray.setUint8(offset, 108);
        offset = byteArray.setUint8(offset, 108);
        offset = byteArray.setUint8(offset, 111);
        offset = byteArray.setUint8(offset, 0);
        byteArray.setFloat32(offset, 1.0);
        os.write(byteList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be ok, but it is rather cumbersome to do it this way. Hope better support for io is coming soon.

Comment: The Dart base libraries are going to be refreshed in the near future. Make sure you file a bug with your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

This has been around for a while, but I searched and didn't find good `DataInput/OutputStream` interoperability classes.  I wanted a version that works with streams, so I could process files that don't comfortably fit in RAM.  So I wrote one.

It's published over at https://pub.dev/packages/jovial_misc in `io_streams`, or if you prefer, https://github.com/zathras/misc/tree/master/dart/jovial_misc.  I made it so it interoperates with `java.io.DataInputStream` and `java.io.DataOutputStream`.  Code using it looks a little like this:

```dart
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:jovial_misc/io_utils.dart';

void main() async {
  final acc = ByteAccumulatorSink();
  final out = DataOutputSink(acc);
  out.writeUTF8('Hello, world.');
  out.close();

  final stream = Stream<List<int>>.fromIterable([acc.bytes]);
  final dis = DataInputStream(stream);
  print(await dis.readUTF8());
  await dis.close();
}
```

The `Stream<List<int>>` would of course typically come from a socket, or `File.openRead()`, etc.  There's also a `DataInputStream` variant that is synchronous and takes an `Iterable`, if you do have all the byte data available up front.

`DataInputStream` and `DataOutputSink` are pretty much the obvious mapping of the `java.io` classes.  The tricky part is the buffer management, since a stream shoves data at you in `List<int>` instances that probably aren't lined up with the data you want.  And, of course, it's necessary to do everything asynchronously.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially asking for arbitrary object serialization. And while the Dart VM has one, it isn't exposed to programmers (it is only used for snapshotting and message passing). I'd say that it would be a mistake to expose it -- in different situations, we have different requirements for serialization and "one true solution" isn't gonna work (Java showed us that already).

For example, I'm working on a MsgPack implementation for Dart, I know that Protobuf port is also in the works, maybe someone will start a Thrift port... the possibilities are endless.

Comment: His requirement is not limited to arbitrary object serialization. I think it is reasonable to have something similar to DataInputstream/ DataOutputStream. These are especially useful if you are reading a binary formatted file with specific layout (Compressed files, Adobe colorbook files, thousands more.) or you want to control exact layout of your output file. Protobufs and others does not provide this.

Comment: Oops, you are right and I was wrong. But then, it's pretty simple to write a simple abstraction on top of ByteArray and OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find is this package: https://github.com/TomCaserta/dart_io/ .  Unfortunately there is a bug when reading to the end of the byte array - see my pull request in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this class:
https://github.com/TomCaserta/dart_io/blob/master/lib/data_output.dart

Unfortunately (a) it doesn't handle streams; (b) writeLong doesn't take a single integer.  I have raised an issue for the Dart SDK: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31166

Edit: I have forked the dart_io package and fixed the two problems described above.  My new package is published as dart_data_io:
https://github.com/markmclaren2/dart_data_io